# Unexpected behavior of GL_SPOT_CUTOFF

Tags: c++, opengl, mfc

Good day all,

I am exploring Lighting in OpenGL with the small MFC app that draws a cube centered in (0,0,0) and a single light source.

However, light source (if I may say - unexpectedly) turns off when I set GL_SPOT_CUTOFF.

This is the code for cube:

```
void CGLRenderer::DrawCube(float a)
{
GLfloat mat_ambient[] = { 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0 };
GLfloat mat_diffuse[] = { 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0 };
GLfloat mat_specular[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat mat_emission[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat mat_shininess = 64.0;

glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, mat_ambient);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, mat_emission);
glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);

//glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);

glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);

glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);

//front
glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glVertex3f(-a / 2, -a / 2, a / 2);
glVertex3f(-a / 2, a / 2, a / 2);
glVertex3f(a / 2, -a / 2, a / 2);
glVertex3f(a / 2, a / 2, a / 2);

//right
glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glNormal3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(a / 2, -a / 2, -a / 2);
glVertex3f(a / 2, a / 2, -a / 2);

//back
glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);
glVertex3f(-a / 2, -a / 2, -a / 2);
glVertex3f(-a / 2, a / 2, -a / 2);

//left
glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glNormal3f(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(-a / 2, -a / 2, a / 2);
glVertex3f(-a / 2, a / 2, a / 2);

glEnd();

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
//top
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glNormal3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(-a / 2, a / 2, a / 2);
glVertex3f(a / 2, a / 2, a / 2);
glVertex3f(a / 2, a / 2, -a / 2);
glVertex3f(-a / 2, a / 2, -a / 2);

//bottom
glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glNormal3f(0.0, -1.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(-a / 2, -a / 2, a / 2);
glVertex3f(a / 2, -a / 2, a / 2);
glVertex3f(a / 2, -a / 2, -a / 2);
glVertex3f(-a / 2, -a / 2, -a / 2);

glEnd();

}
```

And for the light:

```
void CGLRenderer::SetUpLight()
{
GLfloat mod_ambient[] = { 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0 };
glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, mod_ambient);

glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL_FALSE);
glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_LOCAL_VIEWER, GL_TRUE);

GLfloat light0_ambient[] = { 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0 };
GLfloat light0_specular[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat light0_diffuse[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };

GLfloat light0_position[] = { mLight0_x, mLight0_y, mLight0_z, 1.0 };
GLfloat light0_direction[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}; //at the center of the cube

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, light0_ambient);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light0_specular);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light0_diffuse);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light0_position);

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, light0_direction);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 45.0);
//glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, 2.0);

glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

  }
```

No matter what value (0.0-90.0) I set for GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, light0 simply goes off.
Any clue why is this happening? I am very new to OpenGL, so I believe there's something my code is missing or is doing wrong.

This is without setting GL_SPOT_CUTOFF
[image: SPOT_CUTOFF is not set]

This is when GL_SPOT_CUTOFF is set to 45.0
[image: SPOT_CUTOFF is 45]

White point is representing GL_POSITION of light0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a spotlight to work, you need some light direction. However,

```
GLfloat light0_direction[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}; //at the center of the cube
```

is not going to work. You need a direction vector, not the position of some object you want the light to be directed at. The null vector is just no direction at all.

Use the difference between the target point and the light position as the direction vector. But be careful: the light position is set in the local object space defined by the current `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix at the call of `glLight()`.

If you are learning OpenGL now, I strongly recommend that you do *not* learn that stuff at all. OpenGL lighting is part of the *fixed function pipeline* and deprecated since OpenGL 3.0. You should use the *programmable pipeline* ("shaders") nowadays.

Comment: I agree with your last statement, but there's not much I can do, since I need this to pass my exam. I'm going to try out what you proposed about light direction.

Answer (score 0):

By setting `GL_SPOT_CUTOFF` to a directional spot light, you are actually defining a lighting cone:

[image]

In your application, you set the spot light points to the origin (0, 0, 0). Therefore, if your spot light position is very near to your cube with `GL_SPOT_CUTOFF` constraint, only the front face, i.e. the face that facing the light, can get lighted.

By default, the `GL_SPOT_CUTOFF` is `180`, i.e. the light emits in all directions, that's why you could get the cube lighted when `GL_SPOT_CUTOFF` is turned off.

To solve the problem, move the spot light further, or simply turn off the `GL_SPOT_CUTOFF`.

Comment: The position of the light source is already outside of the cube, so that was clearly not the problem. The actual problem is, as derhass have explained, in passing the null-vector for spotlight direction, instead of a direction vector.